# Cómo pasar variable de jQuery a PHP

Tags: php, jquery

Quiero asignar la variable indentificador a una variable php

```
$('#categoria').on('click','.elemento',function() {
               var e = $(this).clone();
               var identificador = $(this).attr("iden");

}
```

Comment: Tienes dos formas: ajax y forms. la primera no recarga la pagina la segunda si.. ¿en que metodo estas interesado?

Comment: sin ajax, men - -

Comment: Amigos genere una nueva pregunta pero esta vez con el codigo completo para que lo puedan captar mas a detalle el problema, saludos espero de su ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Que es lo que quieres hacer una consulta  o guardado?

este es el script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#formu').click(function(){
      var numero_c = $('#numero_c').val();
      var nip = $('#nip').val();
      if($.trim(numero_c).length > 0 && $.trim(nip).length > 0){
        $.ajax({
          url:"inser.php",
          method:"POST",
          data:{numero_c:numero_c, nip:nip},
          cache:"false",
          success:function(data) {

          }
        });
      };
    });
  });
```

este es el php

```
if(isset($_POST["numero_c"]) && isset($_POST["nip"])){
  $numero_c = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["numero_c"]);
  $nip = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["nip"]);
  $sql = "INSERT INTO  (numero_c,nip) VALUES ('$numero_c','$nip');
}
```

Comment: solo pasar la variable

Comment: guardarlo en una variable php

Comment: ESPERO Y TE SIRVA

Comment: hay otra manera sin ajax ??

Comment: manda tu formulario asi <form action=insertar.php> y ay en el php que haga su fincion $numero_c = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["numero_c"]); $sql = "INSERT INTO  (numero_c) VALUES ('$numero_c');

Answer (score 0):

pasalo por ajax a tu archivo php, y recibelo en la variable que desees:

```
$.ajax({url:'archivo.php',method:'post',data:{"identificador":identificador}});
```

y en tu archivo php lo recibes escribiendo:

```
var $identificador = $_REQUEST['identificador'];
```

espero te sirva.

Comment: no e trabajado con ajax aun

Comment: hermano, es la forma de hacer lo que dices, tampoco es algo de otro mundo intentalo para que veas lo facil que es.

Comment: me explicas ese trozo de codigo para analizar el funcionamiento

Comment: ok, tienes una llamada a la funcion de ajax, donde pasamos 3 datos en json(los mas necesarios, se pueden pasar mas), esos datos son:

Comment: 1.- url: la direccion y el nombre del archivo a donde mandaras los datos

Comment: 2.- method: la forma como enviaras los datos: GET o POST

Comment: 3.- data: por ultimo, todos los datos que querramos enviar al servidor, en formato JSON, en este caso, solo queremos una dato "identificador", el nombre que le coloque a la clave del dato, sera como lo llamaras en el array de $_REQUEST del lado del servidor

Comment: solo haciendo eso, ya estas haciendo un uso basico de ajax, y en muchos casos el suficiente.

Comment: y es obligatorio poner REQUEST o puedo poner POST o GET en el caso de resivirlo ?, solo para saber ese detalle

Comment: Puedes poner GET o POST, request captura la que sea